# What route across levels 22-25 avoids all spikes?

Tags: half-minute-hero-the-second-coming

Spikes in levels 22-25 can end a run short by simply draining you down to 1 health with a single misstep. How can you work your way around them?

Answer (score 1):

This will let you go from B22 to B26 safely — while skipping the pickups in B25:

B22: go left; down; right; down; right; down and left.
B23: go up the third arrow (from left to right); left; up; up the 3rd arrow; right; down; right
B24: take the southeast stairs down
B25: go right, then down the second arrow (from left to right).

For the pickups in B25 (you are going to need the stone tracker), you can take the upper right stairs in B24, then move up to find the chest and the timestone. Then walk down across the spikes and then again down the second arrow. Yes, you have taken damage, but now you are right at the exit portal.

> Unless you have all 5 heart shards and 15,000 gold on hand there's probably no point in going deeper anyway...